polynomial divides all the $j$th derivative of $G$ implies it divides $G$?
Let $L(x,y) = Ax + By$ be a linear form and $G(x,y)$ be a binary form of degree $d$. All the coefficients are in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $0 < j < d$. Suppose it is the case that
$L(x,y)$ divides
$$
\frac{\partial^j G }{\partial x^m \partial y^n }(x,y) 
$$
for every $m + n = j$. Is it then the case that $L(x,y)$ divides $G(x,y)$?
Since
$$
x \frac{\partial G }{\partial x }(x,y) + y \frac{\partial G }{\partial y }(x,y)
= d G(x,y),
$$
the statement is true for $j = 1$. But I was stuck with larger $j$... Any comments appreciated!

For multivariate polynomials over any commutative ring, write $(\prod_k\partial_k^{[\alpha_k]}G)(\mathbf{x})$ for the coefficient in the formal Taylor series expansion of $G(\mathbf{x})$:
$$G(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\sum_k\alpha_k=j}\left(\prod_kh_k^{\alpha_k}\right)(\prod_k\partial_k^{[\alpha_k]}G)(\mathbf{x})\text{.}$$
If $G$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ then
$$\binom{d}{j}G(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{\sum_k\alpha_k=j}\left(\prod_kx_k^{\alpha_k}\right)(\prod_k\partial_k^{[\alpha_k]}G)(\mathbf{x})\text{.}$$
For example, for a binary form with $j=2$ over a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra (like $\mathbb{C}$), it holds that
$$\binom{d}{2}G = x^2\cdot \tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{\partial^2G}{\partial x^2} + xy\cdot \tfrac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\,\partial y} + y^2\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{\partial^2G}{\partial y^2}\text{.}$$
Can you fill in the rest?
